# Strange - Android marker location not being updated when dragged unless i add a listener to the map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I have a mapfragment where users drag a marker to a desired location. When done, they press a "Save" button.

Since i'm not interested in the Marker location until the user presses Save, i thought there was no need for listeners, so instead i put the Marker object away and read it again when saving.

```
selectLocationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLoc).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)).draggable(true));
```

...user does stuff and eventually presses Save. In my save-handler method:

```
Log.d(TAG, "performsave selectlocation now has lat;" + selectLocationMarker.getPosition().latitude + ";lon;" + selectLocationMarker.getPosition().longitude);
```

However, i notice that my marker Objects position always has the initial location, even if it has been dragged around!

So, i added a OnMarkerDragListener to my map just to see if the dragging worked. It did, and what's more, i noticed that my marker THEN suddenly becomes updated!
I just added a

```
 map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {.....
```

With empty methods. If i comment it out, my marker lat/lon values are not updated when dragged. If i have the listener, the values ARE updated.

This is very strange to me. The google docs on Markers say:

```
You can get the position of the marker at any time by calling Marker.getPosition()
```

It seems like a weird bug, have i missed something?

Comment: seems strange, although if you try to inspect the classes (no source, just looking at docs and binaries) the position object is final (you can't modify a LatLng object), but is really strange that the getPosition object is not updated.
In my project I have listeners and I need them, but i have done other projects with simple markers draggable and did not find that issue.
Did you try to open an issue?

Comment: Please file a bug here with all the relevant details and steps to reproduce here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/